# Add and format leading zero's in a string

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I want to show a number in my app, and to keep it pretty, display leading zeros to make the layout even.

For example

```
000 500 / 500 000
001 000 / 500 000
100 350 / 500 000
```

I get the first number from an Int, and I want to format it into a string.
Is there a neat way to assure that a number is always six digits, and also get the range of the leading zeros to format them differently?

Comment: Use `NSNumberFormatter`.

Comment: @MartinR Understood which is why my first comment is to use `NSNumberFormatter` so the number looks correct for a given locale.

Comment: The 3-digit separator is localized to whitespace? Or intentionally chosen independently on the locale? Just following the locale may not be what the OP requires.

Comment: @OOPer That can be dealt with by setting up the `NSNumberFormatter` properly.

Comment: @rmaddy, then you insist that all `NSNumberFormatter` related questions needs be in a single thread?

Comment: @OOPer How did you come to that conclusion? I simply posted a comment suggesting using `NSNumberFormatter`. I didn't post an answer, just a suggestion to point the OP in a direction.

Comment: @rmaddy, you are the one who marked this question as duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

`NSNumberFormatter` has everything that you needs:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 6
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal

print(formatter.string(from: 500)!)
print(formatter.string(from: 1000)!)
print(formatter.string(from: 100_350)!)
```

Comment: Don't set a specific separator. Leave the locale's default so each user sees the proper format but with leading zeros.

Comment: Also, NumberFormatter doesn't have an thousandSeparator property..

Comment: I'm using the OS X SDK so `thousandSeparator` is still there. Not realizing that it's the old (pre-10.4) way of doing things. Use `groupingSeparator` instead

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

String extension:

```
extension String {
    func substring(startIndex: Int, length: Int) -> String {
        let start = self.startIndex.advancedBy(startIndex)
        let end = self.startIndex.advancedBy(startIndex + length)
        return self[start..<end]
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var a = 500
var s = "000000\(a)"
print(s.substring(s.characters.count - 6, length: 6))

a = 500000
s = "000000\(a)"
print(s.substring(s.characters.count - 6, length: 6))

a = 50
s = "000000\(a)"
print(s.substring(s.characters.count - 6, length: 6))
```

Comment: How do I use advancedBy in Swift 3?

Comment: take a look at the swift 3 migration guide, https://swift.org/migration-guide/. There is a chapter describing how to migrate `advancedBy` in swift 3. try `myCollection.index(myIndex, offsetBy: …)`

Comment: @Enix good solution you make my day!